# Select Element Does Not Update in Android 2.3.x

Tags: android, html, select

We have a Web application that dynamically builds elements via JS.  We are testing for mobile usability and are finding that on devices that run 2.3.x versions of Android, our select element behavior is a little strange.  A touch on the select element will bring up the usual radio button list of the options and touching an option will select it and return to the page view.  However, the option shown in the select box does not update.  It still shows the top element in the option list.  When the page is reloaded, the behavior is normal.  I have tried adding an additional empty element at the top of the list and setting it as selected when the element is built, which seems to clear up the issue on some devices, but our QA tester is saying that behavior remains on others.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this happen only with the default Android browser or with others?

Comment: Good question.  I don't believe that our testers loaded any additional browsers on the devices.  I think they were testing with the default browser.

Comment: This has been confirmed.  Only the default browser is used on these devices.

Answer (score 1):

If you're fishing for areas to look into, I had a similar issue for select elements when using the fastclick library in any Android 2.3.x browser. The issue was caused by a hack in fastclick for it to work better under Android Chrome. The fix for native browsers hasn't been merged to this day (https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick/pull/190).

On another note Android 2.x can be a nightmare in unexpected places once you start adding an assortment of everyday things - CSS animations, opacity, negative margins outside the screen etc

Comment: Yes ! I had this problem for days, and fast click was the problem. I'll just find a workaround...